# Cannot configure CMake to look for Homebrew installed version of Bison

Tags: cmake, homebrew, bison

I'm running macOS 10.14 and I installed `bison` version 3.2 with `brew`, but it refuses to link:

```
$ brew link bison --force
Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: bison
If you need to have bison first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/bison/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find bison you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/bison/lib"
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` has the following lines:

```
find_package(BISON 3.2 REQUIRED)
...
message(STATUS "Found bison ${BISON_VERSION} at: ${BISON_EXECUTABLE}")
```

`cmake` fails with the following output:

```
Could NOT find BISON: Found unsuitable version "2.3", but required is at
least "3.2" (found /usr/bin/bison)
```

The system-installed `bison` is at version 2.3, and I know that the Homebrew-installed version is at version 3.2.

The `FindBISON` module apparently uses the `find_program` CMake directive, and I've tried adding `/usr/local/opt/bison/bin` to `CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH`, but `/usr/bin/bison` is always selected first no matter what. How can I force CMake to favor the Homebrew installed version of the Bison executable?

Answer (score 12):

Since some things in macos depend on the Apple-provided versions of flex and bison, homebrew installs them outside of the user's normal `$PATH` as a "keg". A manual solution is to make sure you (and your users) add the program's brew prefix to their path (can be found by running `brew --prefix bison` etc.).

An automatic solution is to put this logic in your CMake files. A couple open-source projects have worked around it like this. The earliest example of a fix for this that I could find is from [this commit to STP](https://github.com/stp/stp/commit/dd358def752bce755645d6b0a4606721f3a2df0d) (essential part copied below).

Be sure to clear your CMake cache when messing around with all this, as `BISON_EXECUTABLE` (etc.) is cached.

```sh
# On macOS, search Homebrew for keg-only versions of Bison and Flex. Xcode does
# not provide new enough versions for us to use.
if (CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Darwin")
    execute_process(
        COMMAND brew --prefix bison
        RESULT_VARIABLE BREW_BISON
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE BREW_BISON_PREFIX
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
    if (BREW_BISON EQUAL 0 AND EXISTS "${BREW_BISON_PREFIX}")
        message(STATUS "Found Bison keg installed by Homebrew at ${BREW_BISON_PREFIX}")
        set(BISON_EXECUTABLE "${BREW_BISON_PREFIX}/bin/bison")
    endif()

    execute_process(
        COMMAND brew --prefix flex
        RESULT_VARIABLE BREW_FLEX
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE BREW_FLEX_PREFIX
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
    if (BREW_FLEX EQUAL 0 AND EXISTS "${BREW_FLEX_PREFIX}")
        message(STATUS "Found Flex keg installed by Homebrew at ${BREW_FLEX_PREFIX}")
        set(FLEX_EXECUTABLE "${BREW_FLEX_PREFIX}/bin/flex")
    endif()
endif()

find_package(bison REQUIRED)
find_package(flex REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Damn you saved me. The trick that did it was deleting the contents of CMakeCache.txt and when I ran the cmake operation again, it was able to scan for the correct. I also added /usr/local/opt to the file /usr/paths