# Doxgen uses outdated version of bison OSX Big Sir

Tags: cmake, doxygen, bison, zshrc

I am trying to use Doxygen to create documentation for my code. Following the [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/download.html) documentation, when I run `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..` the compiler tells me

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:112 (message):
  Doxygen requires at least bison version 2.7 (installed: 2.3)
```

However, when I run `bison -V`, I see:

```
bison (GNU Bison) 3.8.2
Written by Robert Corbett and Richard Stallman.

Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

`bison` is included in my path by adding `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/bison/bin:$PATH"` to my `~/.zshrc`. Why might the doxygen cmake command be referencing the old `bison 2.3`?

Comment: On Cygwin I use also the mentioned version and don't get an error (and when debugging I do see that we get version 3.8.2 of Bison). Which version of CMake are you using?

Comment: Maybe you have multiple Bison version on your system and depending on the used shell a different one is selected. Change the line 112 in your CMakeLists.txt into `message(SEND_ERROR "Doxygen requires at least bison version 2.7 (installed: ${BISON_VERSION}, from: ${BISON_EXECUTABLE})")` and see what happens.

Comment: Does setting `-DBISON_ROOT=/usr/local/opt/bison` at the command line fix it?

Comment: @AlexReinking, no I am told that the dbison_root is already that path.

Comment: @albert, I am using cmake version `3.22.1`, and running that command with the updated CMakeLists.txt tells me `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:112 (message):
  Doxygen requires at least bison version 2.7 (installed: 2.3, from:
  /usr/bin/bison)` which is odd because `whereis bison` returns the same path.

Comment: What does `/usr/bin/bison -V` give? Looks like the bison version in `/usr/bin` is the old version and the version in `/usr/local/opt` is not seen. I don't know if the `-DBISON_ROOT=/usr/local/opt/bison` will help otherwise maybe the `-DBISON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/opt/bison` might do it.

Comment: @albert `/usr/bin/bison -V` does indeed return the old version. How do I see the root and/or executable correctly? Is it a command line argument: `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DBISON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/opt/bison ..` or do I add it into my `CMakeLists.txt`? Ie: `set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-DBISON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/opt/bison" )`

Comment: It is a command line argument.

Comment: I may have user permission errors I can't circumvent. `bison -V` returns version 3.8, while `wheris bison` returns `/usr/bin/bison` and `/usr/bin/bison -V` returns version 2.3. I do not know where to go from here. Adding in those command line arguments did not help.

Comment: @RickyAvina were you able to solve the problem? I am in the same bout right now:)

Comment: @Morcus, unfortunately, no. I'll give this another go from Windows in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I did like the comments mentioned : using the `-DBISON_ROOT=/usr/local/opt/bison` argument in the command line.

But first I had the clear the CMake cache.

Here is the commands I ran :

```
rm CMakeCache.txt
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .. -DBISON_ROOT=/usr/local/opt/bison
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this today and actually found a relatively simple solution.  Funnily enough the `message export PATH="/usr/local/opt/bison/bin:$PATH"` is tell you exactly what to do.  Unfortunately the message doesn't tell you the order in which you need it to be. I added the line to my ~/.zshrc at line 3 or 4 before it started to run anything like ohmyzsh which I have installed.  After that problem solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Cannot configure CMake to look for Homebrew installed version of Bison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877344/cannot-configure-cmake-to-look-for-homebrew-installed-version-of-bison)
this post solved my problem.
In my case, I changed the

```
BISON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/bison
```

to

```
BISON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/local/opt/bison/bin/bison
```

and

```
FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_BISON:INTERNAL=[/usr/bin/bison][v2.3()]
```

to

```
FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_BISON:INTERNAL=[/usr/local/opt/bison/bin/bison][v3.8.2()]
```

in CMakeCache.txt and then it worked perfectly.
(/usr/local/opt/bison/bin/bison is what "which bison" tells me)

Comment: I don't think that you should change the CMakeCache.txt  but use `-DBISON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/opt/bison/bin/bison` on the cmake line.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the 'build' folder which is containing CMakeCache.txt.

I upgrade bison 2.7 to 3.X via brew, but CMakeCache.txt has previous version data of bison(2.7) so it failed.

After delete 'build' folder and re-created 'build' folder and execute cmake, It worked.